# HTML dynamic content is not shown in spark textarea

Tags: flex4, mxml

In a flex application, i want to display formatted tweets in a spark textarea but it is showing html elements (with tags) 'as it is' rather parsing it and converting into rich html text, i was following this example from flex official site

```
<s:TextArea width="400" height="100">
    <s:content>This is <s:span color="#FF0000">HTML text</s:span>
        in an <s:span fontWeight="bold">Spark TextArea control</s:span>.
        Use the <s:span textDecoration="underline">content</s:span> property
        of the <s:span color="#008800">Spark TextArea control</s:span> 
        to include basic HTML markup in your text, including
        <s:a href="http://www.adobe.com" target="_blank">links</s:a>.
    </s:content>
</s:TextArea>
```

but passing my data like this

```
<s:TextArea>
    <s:content>{TwitterString.parseTweet(data.text)}</s:content>
</s:TextArea>
```

and the **result** to it for a tweet is,

```
<s:a href='http://t.co/a7bQnmLRGy' target='_blank'>http://t.co/a7bQnmLRGy</s:a> I'll be there
```

which means it has not been formatted as expected.

Any idea how to make `<s:content>` work for dynamic content pass to it?

Please no answers of `TextConverter` this would be my last resort, i would love to use `<s:content>` working

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for `TextArea`'s [content](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html#content) property. In particular, it states this about the `content` property:

> This property is typed as Object because you can set it to to a String, a FlowElement, or an Array of Strings and FlowElements. In the example above, the content is a 2-element array. The first array element is the String "Hello". The second array element is a SpanElement object with the text "World" in boldface.

So the key here is that your `TwitterString.parseTweet()` function is returning a `String`. As such, the `TextArea` is displaying it as a `String` and not bothering to convert the elements found in the text.

Instead, if you wish to continue down this path, your `TwitterString.parseTweet()` function should return an `Array`.  Each element in the array is either a `String` (represents normal text) or some sort of `FlowElement` object (a `SpanElement`, `LinkElement`, `ParagraphElement`, etc.).  If you return an array that contains the structure you want, it will render your content properly. See below for a simple example, it will get very tedious for real content.

So you're really better off using `TextConverter` ... because by writing the code like you want, you are doing **the exact same thing** that `TextConverter` does.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.LinkElement;
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.SpanElement;

            [Bindable("contentChanged")]
            private function getTheContent():Array
            {
                var temp:Array = [];
                var link:LinkElement = new LinkElement();
                link.href = "http://google.com";
                var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
                span.text = "Google";
                link.addChild(span);
                temp.push(link);
                // continue building your structure...(so tedious)
                return temp;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextArea width="400" height="100">
        <s:content>{getTheContent()}</s:content>
    </s:TextArea>
</s:Application>
```